# Error SSAS (v14.0.1.439) Error of data type convert during the processing of measure group

Tags: sql-server, ssas

We migrate from Production SQL Server version 12.0.4100.1 to SQL server version 14.0.3238.1.

And when we process the cube we get this type of error :

```
Errors in the back-end database access module. OLE DB was unable to convert 
a value to the data type requested for column '*****'.
```

We migrate from French server to English version.

The work around to process successfully the dimension was to cast all the numeric data type into float.

It works but the error stay for the measures group.

We try to change the data type in the properties of the measures but it doesn't work.
[image]

Is that a problem of version compatibility or a cast to add on any columns ?

Comment: I had to cast all of my queries and don't forget to cast the query for the partitions if you use this function.

Answer (score 1):

you can change Datatype manually to Double it can works